# Special Logon in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, windows-event-log

I looked at the System logs on my Vista machine.  What is "Special Logon"?  did an administrator log onto my PC?

Answer (score 1):

This is something new for Windows 2008 and Vista (..and probably Windows 7). It is used to audit special logons such as administrators or members of a special group.

let me quote from an [article](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/101060/q-what-is-the-audit-policy-subcategory-special-logon-and-what-is-it-used-for.html):

> The Special Logon auditing subcategory
>   is part of a new auditing feature in
>   Server 2008 and Vista called Special
>   Groups. Administrators can use this
>   feature to find out when a member of a
>   certain group logs on to a specific
>   computer. For example, if you have a
>   file server that's reserved for your
>   organization's research department,
>   you'll always have users other than
>   those in the research department who
>   access the file server, such as the
>   server operators in your IT
>   department. If your research
>   department's file server stores
>   confidential information, the
>   department might ask you to generate
>   an audit trail that specifically logs
>   all file server logon events of server
>   operators. In the legacy Windows
>   auditing system, you would need to
>   enable the Audit logon events category
>   for all users, which would log all
>   logons and logoffs on a system, and
>   then filter for the audit events that
>   are related to server operator account
>   logons. In Server 2008 and Vista, you
>   can use GAPs and the Special Logon
>   audit subcategory to log a specific
>   event each time a member of the server
>   operators' group logs on to the
>   research department's file server.
>
> The Special Logon audit subcategory
>   uses a new registry key called
>   SpecialGroups that you can create on
>   the server in which you want to
>   perform granular auditing, such as the
>   research department's file server in
>   the above example. The SpecialGroups
>   key lists the SIDs of important groups
>   for which you want to track the logon
>   events. If the Special Logon audit
>   subcategory is enabled (remember that
>   it's enabled by default for success
>   events), each time a user that's a
>   member of a group listed in the
>   SpecialGroups key logs on to the
>   server the Windows auditing system
>   will generate an event with ID 4964 in
>   the server's security event log